# Is this an oxymoron?

Tags: oxymoron

> Minimum of up to three years of full-time applicable work experience in municipal solid waste services administration or closely related field.

Is the phrase *minimum of up to three years* an oxymoron?

Comment: ...which part are you asking about?

Comment: minimum of up to three years

Comment: I'd be inclined to say yes, despite there being quite a few hits for the phrase online. "up to three years" would be anywhere from no time at all to three years, so adding "minimum" does seem contradictory to me.

Comment: It's not  an oxymoron so much as the output of a moronic ox.

Comment: I would say that it's simply self-contradictory, whereas an oxymoron should be done deliberately for rhetorical effect.

Comment: An oxymoron is an apparent contradiction in terms (not a real one) stated concisely; it actually makes sense, but it takes quite a time seeing how. But this is an incorrect juxtaposition; 'a minimum of three years' is correct. The 'up to' constraint doesn't make any sense here. It's tantamount to saying 'a minimum of some amount of time (but we're not saying what) between 0 - 3 years'

Comment: I don't think it's an oxymoron as it doesn't contradict itself.  It creates a logical loophole: someone could apply for the job with one second's experience doing the job, and then when questioned later could say "The requirement was "a minimum of up to three years".  1 second is an example of a duration which is "up to three years".  Therefore i have the requisite experience".  At this point, the person who posted the job ad would probably be reprimanded.  So, i think it is really just a "stupid mistake".  It might be an example of "stupidity through over complication".

Comment: "Minimum of up to three years" is equivalent to "Not less than up to three years," which ends up meaning something very similar to "At least zero years." So a person who has negative years of experience might not qualify.

Comment: It is possible that *minimum* is intended to convey the idea that one is **required** to have **some** (more than zero years) experience in the specified field and that *up to* is then intended to convey the idea that there is **no further advantage** to having more than three years of such experience. This may be important if the selection process is heavily bureacratised and points are assigned to candidates for their qualifications. (I am not posting this as an answer, because it is merely a guess; as all contributors to this page agree, the sentence, as it stands, is badly written.)

Answer (score 1):

First, a definition:

> **Oxymoron** *noun*
>   A figure of speech in which apparently contradictory terms appear in conjunction (e.g. *faith unfaithful kept him falsely true*).
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oxymoron)

The keyword is **contradiction**. In the phrase you quoted, namely, *minimum of up to three years*, there is no contradiction. The *minimum* is required to be "up to three years". There is no contradiction because there are possible values that satisfy, e.g. one year.

Here's your quote:

> Minimum of up to three years of full-time applicable work experience in municipal solid waste services administration or closely related field.

This is not a sentence. Everything in the quote after *Minimum* just qualifies the word *minimum*. There is no verb or predicate related to *minimum* (or as an aside, anywhere in the quote).

Whether the quote is *meaningful* is another question, and that depends on the context. For example, suppose there are two pay grades: *junior* and *senior*, where the *senior* pay grade requires 3 years of experience (or if the bureaucrats prefer, a *minimum* of 3 years of experience). One might say the *junior* pay grade requires *no experience*, but if the form of each pay grade must be structured as:

- Minimum of (period) years of full-time ...,

then "up to three" is a plausible, if clunky, phrase to replace *(period)*. Of course, *zero* would be a better replacement.

---

tl;dr **The quoted phrase is not an oxymoron; it is simply a roundabout way of saying that no experience is required.**

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *"minimum of up to three years"* is not an oxymoron because an oxymoron is a concise paradox: a phrase of (usually) two words that contradict each other. Strictly speaking, the two halves of the oxymoron should be contradictory when interpreted literally, and the contradiction should be the "point" of the phrase--i.e., the reader should be impressed that such a thing could exist when logically it should not.

As stated by @Edwin Ashworth in the comments above

> The 'up to' constraint doesn't make any sense here. It's tantamount to saying 'a minimum of some amount of time (but we're not saying what) between 0 - 3 years'

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say. Though it does seem to defeat its purpose - up to three years could just as well be one day! It's really quite a stupid construction. "Minimum of" should just be removed and then "is required" added at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It is **poorly phrased**. Break it into parts. "Up to three years" is a period, which might include (for example) 2 years, 1 year, or 3 years. Then "a minimum of *that period*" is a minimum of 1, 2, 3, etc. years. Since "up to X" has inherently not got a minimum, then it starts at zero; so the minimum of up to X is (I suppose) zero, or no time at all.

But what they (apparently?) meant is "a minimum of SOME experience, NOT none at all, and three years would be a great start" (?).

I work as a computer programmer and it's possible to express certain things in very ridiculous ways which don't sound good, but are logically coherent anyway. (To take a bad example, just to save space, we could correctly describe the number 1 as "any number that is neither smaller than 1 nor greater than 1".) Here we have got a problem of expression. It's not wrong: it's just silly, or a waste of time. If you have to deal with this in an official context, either ignore it, or find the "owner" and highlight the silliness and ask them to change it.